# What number is As?

Tags: pattern

What number does As represent?

[image: blue "He" represents 12, red "Si" represents 24, purple "Fe" represents 36, yellow "As" represents a question mark]

Why?

Hint:

> It is not 48.

Please do not look at the following if you are not color blind. Thanks:

> For the color blind: colors are blue, red, purple and yellow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the simplest possible terms, it can be shown that "As" is:

> **43** - since each number is merely ten greater than the atomic number of the corresponding [Periodic Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) element:
>
>  **He** → Helium (atomic number 2) + 10 = **12**
>  **Si** → Silicon (atomic number 14) + 10 = **24**
>  **Fe** → Iron (atomic number 26) + 10 = **36**
>  so **As** → Arsenic (atomic number 33) + 10 = **43**
>
>  The colours of the symbols are irrelevant - a 'red herring', if you wish...

However, it is also possible to incorporate the symbol colour and to produce a value for "As" of:

> **46** (which was the OP's actual intent, as mentioned in comments below). The formula behind this uses *three* pieces of information:
>
>  - the number of letters in the name of the colour,
>  - the number of letters in the full English name of the chemical element, and
>  - the element's atomic number.
>
>  All we need to do is add the three together...
>
>  Blue **He** → BLUE (4 letters) + HELIUM (6 letters) + atomic number 2 = **12**
>  Red **Si** → RED (3 letters) + SILICON (7 letters) + atomic number 14 = **24**
>  Purple **Fe** → PURPLE (6 letters) + IRON (4 letters) + atomic number 26 = **36**
>  so Yellow **As** → YELLOW (6 letters) + ARSENIC (7 letters) + atomic number 33 = **46**
>
>  It is unfortunate for the OP that for the first three elements chosen, the number of letters in their colour and full name all add up to 10!

Comment: Zl ncbybtl. V pbzcyrgryl vtaberq guvf ehyr!. Gurer vf nabgure ehyr gung vaibyirf gur pbybe juvpu tvirf sbegl fvk! Fbeel nobhg gung.

Comment: @RogerA this answer does have a very neat pattern which works for the question - I'd suggest [posting an updated question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/re-asking-a-question-when-an-unintended-answer-is-given/6983#6983) which has some more examples given which would break this answer.

Comment: @bobble It's alright, I think I've got this :)